# Why use 'piled-up earth supporting a banner for indicating official rank'?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, reopen-closed

First, apologia for offending anyone. I honestly thought [Why use 'piled-up earth supporting a banner for indicating official rank'?](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/70391) was on topic for history!

Second, how can we salvage this question? Closing and deleting feel like a shame, because the comments answer my question well! You have my consent to edit and improve my question!

---

##### 1. Please show me drawings, illustrations of this usage?

#### 2. I have difficulty imagining or picturing why  Chinese officials used "piled-up earth supporting a banner for indicating official rank"?

By definition, "piled-up earth" is ***earthy***, whose synonyms in English are [bawdy, crude, lowbred](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/earthy). Obviously, any Chinese official would hate to be seen as "bawdy, crude, lowbred"! Thus why didn't Chinese officials use posher  materiel to support their banner indicating their rank?

I scanned Christopher Seeley's *The Complete Guide to Japanese Kanji* (2nd edn 2006), pp. 518-9.

> [image]

Comment: This looks like a language question, not a history question.